# File.Copy keeps trying to find a server url by looking for it in my C drive

Tags: c#

I am trying to run the File.Copy function so that I can use a template file I have to make a new word document that the code will fill out. Whenever the code gets to the file.copy function I get the error

"IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect : 'C:\Software\DRAT\DRAT*serverpath*\SoftwareReleaseTool\Trunk\ReleaseNotesTemplates\ReleaseNotes1.docx'"

I want the filename to be

"*serverpath*\SoftwareReleaseTool\Trunk\ReleaseNotesTemplates\ReleaseNotes1.docx"

The first part, "C:\Software\DRAT\DRAT\" is the directory that the project is in. I cannot find out why it keeps looking in this directory for the server link.

I watch the local values before the function is run and they are correct. I get

"*serverpath*/Fusion/Main\Releases\Notes\VCM-1.1.43-SoftwareReleaseNotes.docx"

for notes.ReleaseNotesPath and

"*serverpath*/SoftwareReleaseTool/Trunk/ReleaseNotesTemplates/ReleaseNotes1.docx"

for templatePath.

If I use the paths to the same files that are on my local drive it works, but I need to use the SVN server links so that my co-workers can access the same file from their computers.

Here is the file.copy function that is called:

```
File.Copy(templatePath, notes.ReleaseNotesPath, true);
```

templatePath is filled out by the user, where I input "*serverpath*/SoftwareReleaseTool/Trunk/ReleaseNotesTemplates/ReleaseNotes1.docx"
notes.ReleaseNotesPath is defined here:

```
notes.ReleaseNotesPath = buildFiles[0] + @"\Releases\Notes\VCM-" + model.ReleaseVersion + "-SoftwareReleaseNotes.docx";
```

the buildFiles[0] part of it is "*serverpath*/FusionTest/Main"

I should be making new word document but instead I keep getting the same IOException every time.

Comment: Can you add the exact code that throws the error? as you dont show templatePath being created in the above a little more context may help

Comment: If you want to put the file into SVN, you need to use SVN to do this. `File.Copy` does not know how to talk to SVN.

Comment: It's more that `File.Copy` does not communicate over HTTP protocol.

Comment: In Windows file system you cannot name a folder or a file with ":" in its name. That's why it's trying to convert into an URL.

Comment: Windows directory separator character is "\" not "/". The "/" directory separator is used in linux/mac. Where is that file? is in some website?

Answer (score 1):

File.Copy only works in your local file system. You should try something like System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile

e.g:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("https://ags-iv-engrpub/svn/SoftwareReleaseTool/Trunk/ReleaseNotesTemplates/ReleaseNotes1.docx", "ReleaseNotes1.docx");
}
```

Comment: It also works in network shares `File.Copy("\\servername\sharedFolder\doc.docx", "C:\downloaded\20191017.docx")` works fine.